# Whatsapp API send document Media message

Tags: image, media, whatsapp, document

I'm trying to send a document media message in Whatsapp Business API
using LINK instead of uploading the file, but I got the following error:

```
"errors":[  
      {  
         "code":1008,
         "title":"Required parameter is missing",
         "details":"Parameter 'id' is mandatory for type 'document'"
      }
   ]
```

[image: Facebook Request Definition]

Here is the JSON request object:

```
{  
   "recipient_type":"individual",
   "to":"TELEPHONE_NUMBER_HIDDEN",
   "type":"document",
   "document":{  
      "link":"google-drive/https://drive.google.com/open?id=HIDDEN_DOCUMENT_ID",
      "provider":{  
         "name":"google-drive"
      },
      "caption":"CAPTION MESSAGE"
   }
}
```

Do you have any idea regarding this?
I can't use external services like Twilio.

Comment: the link parameter is not proper. remove the google-drive at the start

Comment: The problem is regarding the id here

Comment: I think the coreapp client you're using is *NOT* above version 2.23.4 because sending a document using its link isn't supported before that and that's why it is always looking for the 'id' parameter in the message.